# Ember.js Error with No Line Number

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have tried so many different things to figure out my problem. I am getting an error I'm guessing in the backburner and it doesn't show what line number my error is on.

**Application Template**

```
{{render 'header'}}
<div class="pageContainer"><!--Page Container-->
    <div class="page"><!--Page-->
        {{#if isDashboardPage}}
            <div class="mainContentDashboard">

                <div class="dashboardCategoryTitle">
                    <span>{{controllers.nav-main.categoryHeader}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="dashboardHeader">
                    <div class="dashboardUsername">
                        <a class="dashboardUsernameLink" href="/profile/username">username</a><span> ( </span>
                        <a class="dashboardUsernameRatings" href="/feedback/username">123</a> <span>)</span>
                    </div>
                    <div id="msg-icon">
                        <id class="counter">123</id>
                        <a href="/messaging/inbox"><i class="glyphicons envelope"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dashboardWallet">
                        <span class="dashboardWalletLabel">4V Wallet balance: </span>
                        <a class="dashboardWalletLink" href="/wallet">$1.00</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {{render nav/main}}
                <div class="dashboardMainContentWrapper">
                    {{render nav/sub}}
                    <div class="dashboardContentWrapper">
                        <div class="dashboardContent">
                            <div class="dashboardContentHeader">
                                {{controllers.nav-sub.categoryHeader}}
                            </div>
                            {{outlet}}//REMOVE THIS NO ERRORS.
                            <p class="loadingLabel">Loading   &nbsp;<i class="icon-refresh icon-spin"></i></p>
                        </div>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{else}}
            <div class="mainContent">
                {{outlet}}
            </div>
        {{/if}}
    </div><!--Page-->
</div>
{{render 'footer'}}
```

I am using grunt ember templates to build the templates, Ember,Ember-Auth, and handlebars. At the part where it says REMOVE THIS, I don't get any errors if I do.

First load works just fine. If I get out of the dashboard, go back, and then click another menu tab I get this error. Here is the log from refresh page, to click out of dashboard, click back, and then click another tab.

**Error Message**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
```

**Error**

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- index.js:394
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0 index.js:394
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0 index.js:394
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.9.1 index.js:394
DEBUG: ------------------------------- index.js:394
Ember Debugger Active
signInSuccess combined-scripts.js:46
Rendering application with default view <(subclass of Ember.View):ember421> Object    {fullName: "view:application"} index.js:394
Could not find "messaging" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {fullName: "template:messaging"} index.js:394
Rendering messaging.inbox with default view <Ember._MetamorphView:ember455> Object {fullName: "view:messaging.inbox"} index.js:394
==================== combined-scripts.js:888
10:50:25 - Value = is dashboard combined-scripts.js:889
==================== combined-scripts.js:890
Rendering createlisting with default view <Ember._MetamorphView:ember690> Object   {fullName: "view:createlisting"} index.js:394
Could not find "createlisting.index" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object  {fullName: "template:createlisting.index"} index.js:394
==================== combined-scripts.js:888
10:50:30 - Value = not dashboard combined-scripts.js:889
==================== combined-scripts.js:890
Rendering dashboard with default view <Ember._MetamorphView:ember717> Object {fullName: "view:dashboard"} index.js:394
Rendering dashboard with default view <Ember._MetamorphView:ember727> Object {fullName: "view:dashboard"} index.js:394
==================== combined-scripts.js:888
10:50:31 - Value = is dashboard combined-scripts.js:889
==================== combined-scripts.js:890
Could not find "messaging" template or view. Nothing will be rendered Object {fullName:   "template:messaging"} index.js:394
Rendering messaging.inbox with default view <Ember._MetamorphView:ember781> Object {fullName: "view:messaging.inbox"} index.js:394
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined
controllerName
Ember.Object.extend.inspectView
(anonymous function)
Ember.Object.extend.appendChildren
(anonymous function)
Ember.Object.extend.appendChildren
(anonymous function)
Ember.Object.extend.appendChildren
Ember.Object.extend.viewTree
Ember.Object.extend.sendTree
sendTree
DeferredActionQueues.flush index.js:5461
Backburner.end index.js:5545
Backburner.run index.js:5584
Ember.run index.js:5915
Ember.EventDispatcher.Ember.Object.extend._bubbleEvent index.js:19034
(anonymous function) index.js:18978
Ember.handleErrors index.js:555
(anonymous function) index.js:18969
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js:3074
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle jquery.js:2750
```

If somebody could help me that would be amazing? If you need any other things to help you out I can provide. If you could also help me out from debugging this in the future it would be great.

Comment: Providing a fiddle might help you for a quicker solution

Comment: @selva-G I don't really know how I would get this all over to fiddle. I really don't want any link to my website for security reasons.